# Setting a value in a pandas dataframe using label and index, now ix is deprecated

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a simulation software measuring performance of an asset. I've created a loop where two parameters in dataframe1, voltage and power, are read and used to look up an efficiency value in dataframe2, using dataframe2.at[x,y].

Currently this causes the "value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice" warning.

In this loop I then want to take the efficiency value and place it in dataframe1['efficiency'] at the appropriate row number, z.

So the code works roughly as

```
for z in range(0,len(dataframe1)):
  x = z['voltage']
  y = z['power']
  #do some other work checking numbers
  dataframe1.loc[:,'efficiency'].iloc[z] = dataframe2.at[int(x),y]
```

The code works as-is, but I am getting this warning. ix has been deprecated which would have allowed this mix of allocations. Is there an elegant way around this issue that still allows using a label?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this warning is because you are taking a slice of a slice - namely you are using two slice methods one after the other (`loc` and `iloc`).

You can avoid this by using *one* slicing method. For example:

```
dataframe1.iloc[z,df.columns.get_loc('efficiency')] = dataframe2.at[int(x),y]
```

In general this is considered more idiomatic Pandas. You can read much more about the topic [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/).

Comment: Fantastic! I knew the problem was a slice of a slice, but hadn't found the get_loc feature which lets you mix the styles within one slicing method. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help :)